# Magento 2 - Color swatches not display in Category Page

Tags: magento2, php, category, category-products, color-swatches

My site in Magento 2.3.5 does not display color samples on the category page.

Instead, they appear on the home page and on the product page.

In the backend I set everything correctly to display the color samples on the category page but they are not seen.

In my custom theme taken by Luma there is this code in list.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work and I return null

Why?

Comment: you are set this `Used in Product Listing = Yes` in your attribute properties from `Admin >> Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes` ???

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes man, i set Product Listing = Yes but not works...

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197287/configurable-swatches-not-showing-on-category-page

Comment: I have seen but this question is for Magento 1.9 and i have 2.3.5 version

Answer (score 2):

I FOUND SOLUTION!

I hope it can help someone:

Copy and paste this code in app/design/frontend/ParentTheme/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml (After category.product.type.details.renderers block)

```
<block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable"
                     name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable"
                     template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml"
                     ifconfig="catalog/frontend/show_swatches_in_product_list">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="configurable_view_model"
                                xsi:type="object">Magento\Swatches\ViewModel\Product\Renderer\Configurable</argument>
                        </arguments>
                </block>
```

Finally copy and paste this code into the file app/design/frontend/ParentTheme/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
                    <?php 
                    $blocks = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable');
                    echo $blocks->setProduct($_product)->toHtml();
                    ?>
```

Enjoy!! ;)

Comment: Not working in Magento 2.4

Comment: also not working for me. i'm using magento 2.3.6. in fact, using this code, all my configurable products turned into simple products :-)